# Get Branch Name After Successful Bitbucket Webhook Call

Tags: php, git, bitbucket, push

On Bitbucket, I have a simple bit of code that does some Git stuff - unimportant.

I want to get the branch name of the code that's been pushed.

I've been trying and not been too successful, but I feel I'm close...

Here's what I've been trying

```
<?php

$payload = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

print_r($payload->push->changes->new->name);
```

I based the payload names from this document

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/event-payloads-740262817.html

but can't seem to get to it.

Can anyone see my error, or do you know a different/better way to get the branch name of the last push?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I knew I was close. I'm putting my answer here for anyone else who might need it.

***Change***

```
print_r($payload->push->changes->new->name);
```

***To***

```
print_r($payload->push->changes[0]->new->name);
```

Comment: you made it simple. in my case, in JS

console.log('res', req.body['push']['changes'][0]['new']['name']);